# Moving average and moving slope in R

Tags: r, moving-average

I am looking to separately calculate a 7-day `moving average` and 7-day `moving slope` of 'oldvar'.

My sincere apologies that I didn't add the details below in my original post. These are repeated observations for each id which can go from a minimum of 3 observations per id to 100 observations per id. The start day can be different for different IDs, and to make things complicated, the days are not equally spaced, so some IDs have missing days.

Here is the data structure. Please note that 'average' is the variable that I am trying to create as moving 7-day average for each ID:

```
id  day outcome average
1   1   15  100 NA    
2   1   16  110 NA    
3   1   17  190 NA    
4   1   18  130 NA    
5   1   19  140 NA    
6   1   20  150 NA    
7   1   21  160 140    
8   1   22  100 140    
9   1   23  180 150    
10  1   24  120 140    
12  2   16  90  NA    
13  2   17  110 NA    
14  2   18  120 NA    
12  2   20  130 NA    
15  3   16  110 NA    
16  3   18  200 NA    
17  3   19  180 NA    
18  3   21  170 NA    
19  3   22  180 168    
20  3   24  210 188    
21  3   25  160 180    
22  3   27  200 184
```

Also, would appreciate advice on how to calculate a `moving 7-day slope` using the same.

Thank you and again many apologies for being unclear the first time around.

Comment: please provide a dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real challenge is to create a `data.frame` after completing the missing rows. One solution could be using `zoo` library. The `rollapply` function will provide a way to assign `NA` value for the initial rows.

Using data from OP as is, the solution could be:

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

# Data from OP
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
     day = c(15L,16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 
                16L, 18L, 19L, 21L, 22L, 24L, 25L, 27L), 
     outcome = c(100L, 110L,190L, 130L, 140L, 150L, 160L, 100L, 180L, 120L, 90L, 110L, 120L, 
                      130L, 110L, 200L, 180L, 170L, 180L, 210L, 160L, 200L)), 
      .Names = c("id", "day", "outcome"), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = "data.frame")

# Make a list without missing day for each id
df_complete <- merge(
  expand.grid(id=unique(df$id), day=min(df$day):max(df$day)),
              df, all=TRUE)

# Valid range of day for each ID group
df_id_wise_range <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(min_day = min(day), max_day = max(day)) %>% as.data.frame()

# id min_day max_day
# 1  1      15      24
# 2  2      16      20
# 3  3      16      27

# Join original df and df_complete and then use df_id_wise_range to 
# filter it for valid range of day for each group
df_final <- df_complete %>%
          left_join(df, by=c("id","day")) %>%
          select(-outcome.y) %>%
          inner_join(df_id_wise_range, by="id") %>%
          filter(day >= min_day & day <= max_day) %>%
          mutate(outcome = outcome.x) %>%
          select( id, day, outcome) %>%
          as.data.frame()

# Now apply mean to get average
df_average <- df_final %>% group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(average= rollapply(outcome, 7, mean, na.rm = TRUE, by = 1, 
          fill = NA, align = "right", partial = 7)) %>% as.data.frame()

df_average
# The result
#   id day outcome average
#1   1  15     100      NA
#2   1  16     110      NA
#3   1  17     190      NA
#4   1  18     130      NA
#5   1  19     140      NA
#6   1  20     150      NA
#7   1  21     160   140.0
#8   1  22     100   140.0
#9   1  23     180   150.0
#10  1  24     120   140.0
#11  2  16      90      NA
#12  2  17     110      NA
#13  2  18     120      NA
#.... 
#....
#19  3  19     180      NA
#20  3  20      NA      NA
#21  3  21     170      NA
#22  3  22     180   168.0
#23  3  23      NA   182.5
#24  3  24     210   188.0
#25  3  25     160   180.0
#26  3  26      NA   180.0
#27  3  27     200   184.0
```

The steps to calculate `moving slope` are:
First create a function to return slope
Use function as as part of `rollapplyr`

```
#Function to calculate slope
slop_e <- function(z) coef(lm(b ~ a, as.data.frame(z)))[[2]]
#Apply function
z2$slope <- rollapplyr(zoo(z2), 7, slop_e , by.column = FALSE, fill = NA, align = "right")

z2
    a  b mean_a slope
1   1 21 NA    NA
2   2 22 NA    NA
3   3 23 NA    NA
4   4 24 NA    NA
5   5 25 NA    NA
6   6 26 NA    NA
7   7 27  4     1
8   8 28  5     1
9   9 29  6     1
10 10 30  7     1
11 11 31  8     1
12 12 32  9     1
13 13 33 10     1
14 14 34 11     1
15 15 35 12     1
16 16 36 13     1
17 17 37 14     1
18 18 38 15     1
19 19 39 16     1
20 20 40 17     1
```

Comment: Thank you so much MKR. Much appreciated. I have edited and clarified my question. My apologies that I wasn't clear the first time around.

Comment: @syork I have modified my answer to use data provided by you. The solution will take care of `average` value. You have to use `df_final` to calculate `slope` as shown by me in example. Let me know if you face any problem. It was good question to answer.

Comment: Thank you so much MKR. I'm trying this out but can't install dplyr. I'm working on this annoying safe haven which only has R version 3.3.0 and I can't update this. It seems like dplyr was developed under R v3.4.1. I tried the r-oldrel version but had no joy. Any thoughts on how to get around this? I can only import packages using Windows binaries. Sorry this is beyond the original question but I would appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, MKR. I'm trying to get the safe haven issue fixed. In the meantime, I tried your solution on my laptop. It worked fine till the step where you calculate df_average. I get the error: "Error: incompatible types, expecting a numeric vector". Am I missing something obvious? Thanks.

Comment: @syork I rechecked everything again at my end and `df_average` is calculated as expected and shown in answer. I have realized that I have not provided code to create data.frame. I have just added even that too as part of my answer.

Comment: Worked like a joy! Absolutely genius! The error I mentioned in previous comment disappeared after I updated R. Massive thank you!

Comment: @syork Fantastic. Welcome!! Try for slope and let me know if you face any prob.

Comment: hope you won't mind me asking how to get the slope to work taking account of repeated observations nested within id? The above code treats each row as a separate observation, but I would like the moving slope to be for each person (same as the moving average, i.e. the calculation restarts for each person). Would be great if this new bit doesn't rely on dplyr which doesn't work on the old version of R on my safe haven. Thank you!

Comment: @syork No issue. I'll take this up tonight and provide a solution for you. Give me another 2-3 hours.